# find a value , copy all rows containing the value and paste it using searchstring and myunion

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have a search by cell value I dont know if the code I have is my best choice. and Im having errors with it, I want to search a cell value from another sheet "Family Ref" in same work book , and when find is done, to copy all rows that include this value and paste is on "view" sheet on a cell/rows range that I choose which always will be same.

with this code the error im having is :select method of range class failed.

any help on my code or suggestion other than my code would appreciate it.

```
Sub select_rows_with_given_string()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim myCell As Object
Dim myUnion As Range

setmycell = Sheets("view").Range("A2")

Set Rng = Selection

Sheets("Family Ref").Select
Columns("A:M").Select


For Each myCell In Rng
    If InStr(myCell.Text, searchString) Then
        If Not myUnion Is Nothing Then
            Set myUnion = Union(myUnion, myCell.EntireRow)
        Else
            Set myUnion = myCell.EntireRow
        End If
    End If
Next

If myUnion Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "No Registration Found."

Else

myUnion.Select
Sheets("view").Select

Selection.Copy
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Recommended reading: [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: thank you, I dont know why my question is closed my code is different than other posts.

Comment: You might consider reading the linked thread (recommended reading) and not using `Select` at all. It'll avoid the error.

Comment: In other words, you don't really need `Sheets("Family Ref").Select`, `Columns("A:M").Select`, `myUnion.Select` or `Sheets("view").Select` or `Range("A5").Select`. The linked thread does a good job of explaining how to improve your code.

Comment: sorry again , but thread explains to use parent object I although i am in the same workbook, just selecting rows from different sheet.

Comment: I know that I have to post a different question, but I have tried same idea of search with iferror index match and vlookup value all together it also did not work as it retrieves only first row of the find, but I have same value in multiple rows, i dont know how to get around that either. so I tried by code and also errors.

Comment: You can't select a range if the parent sheet isn't active. But ... don't select. Selecting is for humans. Code almost always doesn't need to select.

Comment: ok got it Im trying the parent way  now, but if error invalid use of me keywords , what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `Me`. Instead `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Yourworksheetname").Activate` ... but again, don't do this.

Comment: I thought the me. is for the parent object which is better that my method . what do u suggest I should do?